# Include PHP code in html error

Tags: php, html, image

Am working with an small php project . in creating an text generating image. took some sample codes and tired.

```
    <?php

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);


header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($im);

imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

i made some changes and it works good . when i tried to insert this php file in other html file using   it results broken image. how can i solve this why it happens.

Comment: Get rid of the spaces before the `<?php`. Also, if that doesn't work, comment out the header line and paste any errors you're getting here.

Comment: This script renders an image.  You can't just insert it into HTML, short of base-64 encoding the image data.  Also, see Rekire's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the same page being both HTML and an image. The way you do what you want is by having the HTML file contain an `IMG` tag that references this script.

```
<img src="yourscript.php">
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you don't have any whitespace before your `<?php` statment. In your example above there are 4 spaced before the `<?php`. Note that this also is important for empty lines.

Comment: In addition, a closing `?>` tag is unnecessary in scripts that are entirely PHP.  This will prevent empty lines at the end of the script from affecting things.

Answer (score 0):

An HTML file cannot have multiple header sections.  Once you have rendered content on the page  the call to `header()` will generate an error.